# IPv6 connections from outside the LAN are timing out; what is blocking the connection?

Tags: ipv6, connection, troubleshooting

as I understand with ipv6 there is no NAT so every client on a network will get a different public ip address (so there is no need for port forwarding). so I checked on my network and indeed every computer has a different public ipv6 address which I can ping and ssh to from inside the local network.
But when I try to access the address from outside the network (either ping6 or ssh) the connection times out.

Is my local machine blocking the connection or my router or my isp?

Comment: Did you check your firewall?

Comment: IPv6 has multiple classes of address space, are you using the publically routable address or link local address?

Comment: Like Jim B said. It *might* be worthwhile to give us an example address. Feel free to obfuscate the last several octets, but leave the first three 16-bit words alone.

Comment: Just because you have a public address doesn't mean that people can get to you.  Stateful firewalls can easily permit outgoing traffic, while blocking incoming traffic.

Answer (score -1):

If you can connect to the internet from your local machine, the issue should be on the router.
For security reason, it is not good to let direct access from internet to your local machines, except if you know what you are doing. To prevent attack and scans.
As IPv4 you can have local IPV6 addresses and be connected to internet throw NAT that is still a good configuration.